# Propagation possion errors on scaled count bins

Tags: poisson-distribution, sum

I have a count-channel histogram, where the counts have a standard Poisson uncertainty - if bin $i$ has $C_i$ counts then the uncertainty is $\sqrt{C_i}$.

Now if I were to sum all the bins my job would be easy - the entire histogram would be considered a bin with Poisson noise, and the uncertainty would be

$\sqrt{\sum_i C_i}$

The thing is, I have to divide each bin by an effective area $E_i$. Assume there is no uncertainty here, so my result is:

$f=\sum_i \frac{C_i}{E_i}$

One option would be just to treat this as a Gaussian combination, to yield:

$\mathrm{d}f=\sqrt{\sum_i\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}C_i}{E_i}\right)^2}=
\sqrt{\sum_i\left(\frac{\sqrt{C_i}}{E_i}\right)^2}=
\sqrt{\sum_i\frac{C_i}{E_i^2}}$

How valid is this treatment? Is there a better known way to combine such a trivial scaling of Poisson variables? Please only provide cited answers.

Just in case, my question is more specialized than https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304762/propagating-asymmetric-and-large-errors-in-a-ratio-of-likelihood-fit-parameters (I think there is one one stats as well), so I'm hoping there is a solution.